# Explanation of this proof (different subspaces have different annihilators)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The statement reads: if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, then if $ann(W_1) = ann(W_2)$ then $W_1 = W_2$ where

$$ann(W) = \{ f \in V^*: f(v) = 0, \forall v \in W\}$$

is the annihilator.

Now the proof in the notes reads like this: to prove $ ann(W_1) = ann(W_2) \Rightarrow W_1=W_2 $ we proceed by contraposition; suppose $ W_1 \neq W_2$ then there is some vector $\alpha \in W_1 \setminus W_2$. Now suppose $B_{W_2} = \{w_1,...,w_k\}$ be a basis of $W_2$. Then $ B_{W_2}\cup \{ \alpha \}$ is linearly independent since $\alpha\notin W_2$. Extend $ B_{W_2}\cup \{ \alpha \}$ to a basis of $V$ by $B_V=\{w_1,...,w_k,\alpha,w_{k+2},...,w_n\}.$
Now define a (unique) linear functional $f:V\rightarrow \Bbb F $ such that $f(w_i)=0$ for $ i=1,...,k \quad; f(\alpha)=1_{\Bbb F} \; $and $f(w_j)=1_{\Bbb F}$ for $j=k+2,...,n$. Then clearly $f(w)=0 \; \forall  w\in W_2 $ (since $\forall w \in W_2 \;, w=a_1w_1+...+a_kw_k \; $for some $a_1,...,a_k \in \Bbb F$) i.e $f \in ann(W_2)$ but $f\notin ann(W_1)$ since $\alpha \in W_1 $ and $f(\alpha) \neq 0$. Hence $ ann(W_1) \neq ann(W_2)$.

I understood the most of the proof, but there are two things I miss, and probably they are stupid things.

- I might be drunk, but why $f(\alpha) = 1_{\Bbb F}$ and the same for $f(w_j)$?
- When we define a unique functional, shouldn't it be $f: V^* \to \mathbb{F}$ instead of $f: V \to \mathbb{F}$?

Thank you.

Here is assumed $\dim(V) = n$.

Comment: Doesn't this require an extra condition, such as the subspaces being closed?  I'm thinking of the subspace  $W_2$ of $\ell^2$ consisting of all sequences with $a_1=0$ and the subspace of $W_1 \subseteq W_2$ consisting of all sequences in $W_2$ with finite support.

Comment: @RobertShore I forgot to specify perhaps that $dim(V)$ is finite

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually simply *define* $f$ such that $f(\alpha) = 1_{\mathbb F}$ and the $f(w_i) = 0$. This is a case of the general construction of a basis `dual' to a given one. This $f$ is well-defined since we've defined its values on a basis.

For your second question: a functional on $V$ is a map $V \to \mathbb F$ i.e. element of $V^*$, not a map $V^* \to \mathbb F$.

It's also nice to note that there is actually an order-reversing correspondence between subspaces of $V$ and subspaces of $V^*$ here; you can take double annihilators and get back the original subspace under the double dual isomorphism $V \simeq V^{**}$ (exercise).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I missed it was a definition then, no particular reason (maybe for simplicity)

Comment: Minor quibble: $f(w_j)$ is defined as $1$ not $0$ for some of the $w_j$, not that that matters.

Comment: Sorry yes, good point

Answer (score 1):

For your first point, perhaps a little drink might help! Seriously, you need $f(a) \neq 0$ so that $f \not\in \operatorname{ann}(W_2)$ and $f(a) = 1_{\Bbb{F}}$ is as good a choice as any for that. For the $f(w_j)$ with $j > k + 1$, it doesn't matter what value you choose, the author has chosen a specific value for definiteness, I guess.

For your second point, $V^*$ the set of means the set of linear mappings $f : V \to F$, so $V \to F$ in the proof is correct, although the author could have said $V^*$ instead.

Comment: Using `\operatorname` rather than `\mathrm` gives you better spacing.

Comment: @RobertShore: thanks and agreed. However, I should have put brackets round the operand anyway like the OP did and then it doesn't make any difference.